# PHP in HTML not working properly

Tags: php, html, syntax, character

I have the following code in my [index](http://dzprototype.byethost31.com/)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>DZ Prototype</title>
<link rel="icon" type="img/ico" href="images/favicon.jpg">
 </head>
 <body>
<center>
<h1>Welcome to DZ Prototype Testing Area!!</h1>
</center>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="http://images1.knowable.com/live/articles/2_1ec282dc7578c9356aef339b8b98bbe9.gif" alt="It works!!"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<div align="center">
<?php

$theFile = "cowrie.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
echo $line[18];

if (trim($line[18]) == "Incorrectly Classified Instances         1              100      %") { 
    echo "<h2><font color=red>Possible Malicious Login Attempt</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2><font color=green>Status Green</h2>";
}

?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It appears that there must be an character that is mixing the whole php syntax, not sure which one though.

cowrie.txt still needs to be uploaded so for now nothing in the php has to be displayed since there is no file.

Comment: The PHP is showing up in the HTML. Does your host support PHP?

Comment: So how can you echo $line[18] if there is no file?

Comment: looks like the PHP is not available there

Comment: @aynber just checked and it appears for pages to support php they need to be renamed to .php at the end

Comment: Also you have to  trim before compare

Answer (score 0):

Your demo works, so PHP works fine. Must be something with your cowrie.txt file. The following code works just fine (with a simulated lines array):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>DZ Prototype</title>
<link rel="icon" type="img/ico" href="images/favicon.jpg">
 </head>
 <body>
<center>
<h1>Welcome to DZ Prototype Testing Area!!</h1>
</center>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p style="text-align:center"><img src="http://images1.knowable.com/live/articles/2_1ec282dc7578c9356aef339b8b98bbe9.gif" alt="It works!!"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div align="center">
<?php
//$theFile = "cowrie.txt";
//$line = file($theFile);
//echo $line[18];

// Simulated line array for demonstraiton purposes
$line = array("ewfefe", "ewfewfewf", "54g5grthrhryt", "Incorrectly Classified Instances         1              100      %");

if (trim($line[3]) == "Incorrectly Classified Instances         1              100      %") { 
    echo "<h2><font color=red>Possible Malicious Login Attempt</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2><font color=green>Status Green</h2>";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your cowrie.txt file for special characters, tabs, line breaks, etc. The comparison will fail on that too, and it's invisible.

Answer (score 0):

> **Your index files extension seems like `index.html`. Change it to `index.php`**
>   Use `file_exists()` function

As well add `''` in `class` attribute

```
if (trim($line[18]) == "Incorrectly Classified Instances 1 100 %") 
{ 
    echo "<h2><font color='red'>Possible Malicious Login Attempt</h2>";
} 
else {
    echo "<h2><font color='green'>Status Green</h2>";
}
```

---

### So Final Well-Form code is

```
$theFile = "cowrie.txt";

if(file_exists($theFile))
{
    $line = file($theFile);
    echo $line[18];

    if (trim($line[18]) == "Incorrectly Classified Instances 1 100 %") 
    { 
        echo "<h2><font color='red'>Possible Malicious Login Attempt</h2>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<h2><font color='green'>Status Green</h2>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "File doesn't exist";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My host [byethost] has to have pages containing php be named as php. So what I did was rename index.html to index.php and so now it only displays `Green Status` since the file does not exists and the trim function returns a false value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. is file available in place?. 
use single code for equalization

```
if (trim($line[20]) == '$line = file($theFile);') { 
    echo "<h2><font color=red>Possible Malicious Login Attempt</h2>";
} else {
    echo "<h2><font color=green>Status Green</h2>";
}
```